# Cryptocurrency Wallet 3rd party access

Tags: transactions, private-key, api, public-key, javascript

Do Crypto wallets such as Exodus etc have something like an API? For example is it possible to perform a cryptocurrency transaction directly from the web browser client (using the specified amount and public/private keys) with an html form or something similar?

Comment: I think this answer will differ if your question is about Exodus specifically or wallets like Exodus. Could you clarify which one it is?

Comment: anything. i don't mind if it is something different than exodus